# LeftJoin não trás os valores do id - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, join

Estou utilizando o leftJoin para trazer os dados de 2 tabelas que estão vinculadas por um método BelongsToMany para a minha view de index.
Praticamente todos os dados das duas tabelas aparecem quando dou um `dd` na minha variável, exceto o `$id` do meu usuário.
Rodando esse código:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $setores = Setores::get();
    $filiais_user = User::leftJoin('filiais_users','users.id','filiais_users.users_id')
                        ->leftJoin('filiais','filiais.id','filiais_users.filiais_id')
                        ->select('users.*','filiais.id');

    dd($filiais_user);
```

É isso que é retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu Model de usuários, tenho o relacionamento desta maneira:

```
public function filiais()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Filial', 'projeto.filiais_users', 'filiais_id','id');
}
```

Já tentei especificar no select para que ele selecionasse a coluna `id` na tabela `users`, porém ele continua retornando sem os valores desta coluna. Alguém consegue indicar onde está meu erro ou alguma forma que possa resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que precisa do ->get() para enviar a builder

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $setores = Setores::get();
    $filiais_user = User::leftJoin('filiais_users','users.id','filiais_users.users_id')
                        ->leftJoin('filiais','filiais.id','filiais_users.filiais_id')
                        ->select('users.*','filiais.id')->get();

    dd($filiais_user);
```

Comment: Mesmo com o `->get()`, o `id` ta retornando valor Null

Comment: coloca seu model inteiro para dar uma olhada

Comment: Consegui resolver, tirei os `join` e utilizei só um `with` puxando a função filiais que já tinha na model, agradeço sua ajuda. Irei encerrar a pergunta